# How to get dependency injection working with IAsyncAuthorizationFilter in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac

I have implemented the `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` interface to a class; in addition, that class is derived from `Attribute`, so that I can mark controller classes and action methods using it. This works so far; the `Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)` method is called before the action method, and if the request is not authenticated, an `HTTP 401` is returned for the response.

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class CustomAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter 
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This attribute is used as follows...

```cs
[CustomAuthenticationAttribute]
public class SomeDataController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task GetData()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I want to use an application service (which obtains secret private key information required for authentication from a database) and tried to use property injection for that. Injecting dependencies via the ctor is not a good choice here since it´s implemented as an attribute. So I tried...

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class CustomAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter 
{
    public IPrivateKeyLookupService KeyService { get; set; }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        string publicKey = ...
        ...
        var privateKey = await this.KeyService.GetPrivateKeyFrom(publicKey);
        ...
    }
}
```

...but property injection does not seem to work here. The service is registered with the IoC, but properties do not get wired. This is an ASP.NET Core 1.1 project in which I use `Autofac`. In the `Startup` class my `ConfigureServices` method has something like that...

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServicesCollection collection)
{
    ...

    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<AuthKeyService>().As<IPrivateKeyLookupService>();

    containerBuilder.Populate(services);

    this.container = containerBuilder.Build();
}
```

Does `Autofac` support auto-wiring for `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` types? And if not, how could I polyfill that functionality?

Comment: Have you tried registering your filter on the controller with `[TypeFilter(typeof(CustomAuthenticationAttribute))]` instead? You can get more info here: https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-di-deep-dive

Comment: @juunas Thanks; just found that solution a few minutes ago. That´s typical... I was looking for hours, and then right after I asked the question the solution popped up (-;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turned out to be very simple...

In `ASP.NET Core` there is the `TypeFilter` attribute which is also a filter that creates another filter (specified by `Type`) and satisfies its constructor arguments by involving dependency injection.

I changed the implementation of `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`; removed the properties and added a ctor instead, because with `TypeFilter` ctor injection would work now...

```cs
public sealed class CustomAuthenticationAttribute : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter 
{
    private readonly IPrivateKeyLookupService keyService;
    public CustomAuthenticationAttribute(
        IPrivateKeyLookupService keyService)
    {
        this.keyService = keyService;
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I also removed inheritance from `Attribute` because it´s not needed anymore as well as the declaration of the `AttributeUsage` attribute.

So, I can use my attribute as follows...

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(CustomAuthenticationAttribute))]
public class SomeDataController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task GetData()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Passing additional arguments to the filter´s ctor is also possible via the `object[] Arguments` property of the `TypeFilter` class.

Comment: Huge props. This is definitely the simple way to check an api key

Comment: Well done that man! Just another example of the hoops one has to jump through for dependency injection, but thank you for sharing :)

Answer (score 3):

A normal thing one needs to do is get ISomething that you registered previously, especially when you implement custom attributes bet really anywhere in the HTTP pipeline will work.

Basically what you like to do is get your "hands" on a HttpContext and use the IServiceProvider located in HttpContext.RequestServices

From there it's all easy sailing if you included

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

Let me demonstrate this in a small sample where I get to the registered IMemoryCache (you need to register it for this to work of course by adding services.AddMemoryCache(); in your startup.cs)

Here is the copy past stuff:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class SomeAttribute : Attribute,IAuthorizationFilter
{        
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context )
    {
        IMemoryCache memory= context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
    }
}
```