# Not able to use DI for logging in AuthorizationFilter

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog

I still don’t have Dependency Injection down and I’m new with .Net Core (using 3.1.5). I’ve created an AuthorizationFilter for a WebAPI. What I’m still not understanding is how I can pass my Nlog to the attribute.

I have the following as my AuthorizaitonFilter

```
public class TokenAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public TokenAttribute(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Authorizing");

            //Get the values from the Request Header
            context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Api-Token", out var token);
            context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Customer", out var customer);

            //Query to look up Customer and Token

            using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
            {
                var results = ctx.Token.FromSqlRaw(sbQuery.ToString()).ToList();

                if (results == null || results.Count == 0)
                {
                    context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Invalid Token");
                    return;
                }

                return;                
            }
        } 
    }        
}
```

However, I’m getting an error on my Token attribute. If I leave it as just `[Token]` I complains with a message: `“There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter”`. I get that because the Token attribute’s constructor is looking for a ILogger.

```
[Token]
        [AcceptVerbs(WebRequestMethods.Http.Get, WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)]
        public ShiftRequest Post([FromBody] ShiftRequest m)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Calling POST command.");
```

Then if I try to pass _logger to the Token Attribute it complains with `“An object reference is required for the non-static field ‘ShiftController._logger’”`.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ShiftController : ControllerBase
{
    private IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly ILogger<ShiftController> _logger;

    public ShiftController(ILogger<ShiftController> logger, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
        _logger = logger;
    }
        
    [Token(_logger)]
    [AcceptVerbs(WebRequestMethods.Http.Get, WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)]
    public ShiftRequest Post([FromBody] ShiftRequest m)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Calling POST command.");
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
public class TokenAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TokenAuthorizationFilter> _logger;
        public TokenAuthorizationFilter(ILogger<TokenAuthorizationFilter> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Authorizing Token");

            //Get the values from the Request Header
            context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Api-Token", out var token);
            context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Customer", out var customer);


//Query to check username and password

            using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
            {
                var results = ctx.Token.FromSqlRaw(sbQuery.ToString()).ToList();

                if (results == null || results.Count == 0)
                {
                    context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Invalid Token");
                    return;
                }

                if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
                }

                return;
            }
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<TokenAuthorizationFilter>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

Controller

```
 [ServiceFilter(typeof(TokenAuthorizationFilter))]
        [AcceptVerbs(WebRequestMethods.Http.Get, WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)]
        public ShiftRequest Post([FromBody] ShiftRequest m)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Calling POST command.");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get dependency injection working with IAsyncAuthorizationFilter in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275879/how-to-get-dependency-injection-working-with-iasyncauthorizationfilter-in-asp-ne)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to subclass `Attribute` in this case. For authorization filters, these can be added via a `[ServiceFilter(type)]` attribute on the action. When the `ServiceFilter` attribute is used, [all dependencies are injected automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#servicefilterattribute) via ASP.NET Core's built-in service provider.

In your code, this would look something like `[ServiceFilter(typeof(TokenAttribute))]`, although as a personal suggestion it might be more appropriate to name it something like `TokenAuthorizationFilter`.

Note that you'll have to register your `TokenAttribute` as a service inside `Startup.cs` or wherever your HTTP pipeline setup is happening.

Comment: Thanks. I created a new TokenAuthorizationFilter and then followed along with that documentation and got it to compile and walk through the code. It's not logging any more so I'm going to have to check my NLog setup but at least I could debug through the code. I will say that one positive of using Authorization like I was doing caused it to go to the filter prior to the API code. With the ServiceFilter it goes through the API code first and then through the filter which is kind of backwards.

Comment: Maybe I’m misunderstanding you, but Authorization filters are the first thing to run once a request hits server side. The actual action code will not run before the authorization filter completes. I’m guessing you’ve mistakenly used a IResultFilter, which runs after, instead of an IAuthorizationFilter, as recommended above. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#filter-types.

Comment: Authorization does happen first but I switch to IResultFilter based on the article. If you use IResultFilter it will run after the API code. I then went back to the IAuthorizationFilter and now it fires off first before the API code. I put my results in the original post. NLog isn't working at all now so I'll have to try to fight that next.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear you got it :).

Comment: Great! I tried @BenSampica method and worked it for me. thx.

Answer (score 1):

As I was not able to use DI for logging in AuthorizationFilter in an easy way, I decided to do it cleaner at least for me, then I created a static class as a global configuration class as indicated in this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676152/asp-net-core-web-api-logging-from-a-static-class).

```
/// <summary>
/// Shared logger. It is useful because it is complicated to use ILogger from static classes.
/// </summary>
public static class ApplicationLogging
{
    public static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory { get; set; }

    public static ILogger CreateLogger<T>() => LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>();

    public static ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName) => LoggerFactory.CreateLogger(categoryName);

    public static ILogger CreateLogger(Type type) => LoggerFactory.CreateLogger(type);
}
```

Then, I loaded the global configuration class at Startup.cs in the Configure() method, as in this example:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, GateKeeperDbContext dbContext, ILogger<Startup> logger, ILoggerFactory logFactory)
    {
        // Logging
        logFactory.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
        ApplicationLogging.LoggerFactory = logFactory;
        
        ...
    }
```

Then, at your Filter, you can put as is provided in this example:

```
public class TokenAuthorizationFilter: IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly ILogger<TokenAuthorizationFilter> _logger;

    ...

    public TokenAuthorizationFilter(string[] roles)
    {
        _logger = ApplicationLogging.LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<TokenAuthorizationFilter>();

        ...
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Authorizing");
        
        ...
    }
```

Please remember this is an example, you should put parameters in your constructor according your needs.

All my examples were done using Net Core 5 and I hope this help suits you well. And I feel glad on receiving constructive comments.