# How to Resolve/inject Dependency for Attribute based class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am creating the following attribute class in an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API.

I need to make a database call from this class and want to get `dbContext` which is already registered with dependency container.

How do I inject the dbcontext into my `customAuthorization` class ?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class CustomAuthorization : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
   private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    
   public CustomAuthorization(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
          _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
   }


   public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
   {
       ...................
   }

}

[CustomAuthorization()]
public class OrganizationController : CustomControllerBaseClass
{
    // .......
}
```

Comment: The issue is not in the filter calls but with the Declaration of Attribute on OrganizationController , it expects IServiceProvider to be passed in from Customauthorixation class

Answer (score 2):

`IAuthorizationFitler` has a `OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)` method, doesn't it?
You could use the `filterContext.HttpContext.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService...`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class CustomAuthorization : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        var context = filterContext.HttpContext.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Your_DbContext>();  
        ...                                      
    }
}
```

Though, I don't know the scope of the `AuthorizationFilter`, whether it's singleton, scoped or transient: if it's singleton, you could create a scope on your own:

```
using(var scope = filterContext.HttpContext.ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Your_DbContext>();  
    ...                                      
}
```

I don't know whether I'm wrong somewhere OR there is an easier approach, but this is my quick response.

Comment: The signature for OnAuthorization is different in .net
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
{
}

Comment: Actually this link helped
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69310490/1764116

Comment: @nss Just a typo, sorry. Edited!